# Setting the minimum date of jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working on a project which involves using HTML5 and Javacript/JQuery. I am trying to make use of the Jquery datepicker and trying to set the minimum date to today's date so the user can't select a date from yesterday.

Below is my Javascript.

```
$(function()
            {
               var today = new Date();
               $("#txtStartDate").datepicker(
                    {
                        changeMonth: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 1,
                        minDate: new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth() +1, today.getDay()),
                        onClose: function(selectedDate)
                        {
                            $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy", selectedDate);
                        }
                    });
            });
```

It doesn't seem to be making any difference as I can still go back to days before yesterday.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you did'nt read the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) ?

> ***minDate***
>
> **Type**: Date or Number or String
>
> Default: null 
>   The minimum selectable date. When set to null, there is no minimum. 
>   Multiple types supported:
>
> Date: A date object containing the minimum date.
>
> ***Number: A number of days from today.*** <- set to 0, it's no days from today !

So setting minDate to 0 should work, right !

```
$(function () {
    var today = new Date();
    $("#txtStartDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot easier, that whast I was trying to do.